# Type level indicator function for a type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

For my nefarious and mostly incomprehensible reasons, I've decided to want a type level
function that would indicate presence of type class instance for a type. It would work like this:

```
 > :kind! HasClass Show Int
 > 'True
 > :kind! HasClass Monoid Int
 > 'False
```

Given the Constraint types etc. added to GHC lately, I have a feeling that this might be possible, but no tidy implementation comes to mind. Can it be done?

Comment: shouldn't be possible (as a type function) as it violates the open world assumption. You might be able to do it with overlapping instances and fun deps though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this?

```
class HasClass (c :: * -> Constraint) a where
  type Has c a :: Bool

instance HasClass c a where
  type Has c a = 'False

instance (c a) => HasClass c a where
  type Has c a = 'True
```

Provided you don’t mind a few extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

Comment: Gives "Duplicate instance declarations... Conflicting family instance declarations" in GHC 7.8.x.